# Binance TIMESTAMP ERROR (Timestamp for this request is outside of the recvWindow. M 1)

Tags: unix-timestamp, binance

I'm using binance broker api, when executing my code.

*I got this error :*
**data: {
code: -1021,
msg: 'Timestamp for this request is outside of the recvWindow.'
}**

*Then I have used binance server timestamp and get another error :*
**data: { code: -1022, msg: 'Signature for this request is not valid.' }**

```
----- My sample code -------

'use strict'

//Modules
const crypto = require('crypto');
const axios = require('axios');
const moment = require('moment');
const keys = require('./config/keys');


//Keys
const apiKey = keys.keys.apiKey;

async function api_call(config){
  var response  = {}
  try {
    response = await axios(config);
    response =  {
      error: false,
      data : response.data
    }
  } catch (error) {
    response =  { 
      error: true,
      data : error
    }
  }
  return response;
}


async function get_binance_server_time(recvWindow=50000){
  var timestamp = moment().unix();
  var serverTime = 0;

  var config = {
    method: 'get',
    url: `https://api.binance.com/api/v3/time`,
    headers: { 
      'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
      'X-MBX-APIKEY': apiKey 
    }
  };  
  var response = await api_call(config);

  if(response.error){
    response.data = {
      serverTime : serverTime
    }
  }
  serverTime = response.data.serverTime

  console.log(timestamp);
  console.log(response.data.serverTime);

  if (timestamp < (serverTime + 1000) && (serverTime - timestamp) <= recvWindow) {
    console.log("process");
  } else {
    console.log("Rejected");
  }
  return serverTime;
}


async function get_broker_account_information( _signature = null){

  // Make the api call here
  var serverTime  = await get_binance_server_time();
  var _timestamp = serverTime;

  const query_string = `timestamp=${_timestamp}`;
  const recvWindow = 50000
  const signature = crypto.createHmac('sha256', apiKey).update(query_string).digest('hex')

  var config = {
    method: 'get',
    url: `https://api.binance.com/sapi/v1/broker/info?timestamp=${_timestamp}&signature=${signature}&recvWindow=${recvWindow}`,
    headers: { 
      'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
      'X-MBX-APIKEY': apiKey 
    }
  };  
  
  var response = await api_call(config)
  console.log(response.data);
  return response;
}




// create_sub_account()
get_broker_account_information()
// get_binance_server_time()
```

Comment: Just a heads up .. and I know its quite a few years away .. but be aware that on 
January 19, 2038 the UNIX TIMESTAMP will hit end of life, so do what you will with this information.  It is a 32 bit number and that date will reach the end of the span.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Binance requires Unix timestamp in Milliseconds.
So you should change

```
var timestamp = moment().unix();
```

to

```
var timestamp = moment().unix()*1000;
```

Some time sync issues can be resolved by using an offset of about 15 seconds:

```
const offset = 15000;
var timestamp = moment().unix()*1000 - offset;  // works flawlessly in my case
```

Also try using

```
const recvWindow = 60000  // maximum allowed
```

**Important:**
Your signature has to be generated from secret key, not api key. You need both, api key in header, secret key in signature calculation.

To gerenate a valid signature, all query parameters must be in the queryString, which you use to generate the signature.

Make a parameters object and convert it to a queryString:

```
var params = {
    'timestamp': _timeStamp,
    'recvWindow: 60000,
    // other query parameters
};

var queryString = Object.keys(params).map(key => key + '=' + params[key]).join('&');
```

Then generate signature:

```
const signature = crypto.createHmac('sha256', apiSecret).update(queryString).digest('hex')
```

Comment: Thanks,

But I have this new error :  data: { code: -1022, msg: 'Signature for this request is not valid.' }
````

Comment: My code : 
```
const offset = 15000;
  var _timestamp = moment().unix()*1000 - offset;  // works flawlessly in my case

  const query_string = `timestamp=${_timestamp}`;
  const recvWindow = 60000
  const signature = crypto.createHmac('sha256', apiKey).update(query_string).digest('hex')

  var config = {
    method: 'get',
    url: `https://api.binance.com/sapi/v1/broker/info?timestamp=${_timestamp}&signature=${signature}&recvWindow=${recvWindow}`,
    headers: { 
      'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
      'X-MBX-APIKEY': apiKey 
    }
  };
```

Comment: don't use the apiKey to create the signature! Use the secret key. I wrote in in my answer.

Comment: I changed,
Still got the error

Comment: // Make the api call here
  const offset = 15000;
  var timestamp = moment().unix() * 1000 - offset;  // works flawlessly in my case
  const query_string = `timestamp=${timestamp}`;
  const recvWindow = 60000
  const signature = crypto.createHmac('sha256', secretKey).update(query_string).digest('hex')

  var config = {
    method: 'get',
    url: `https://api.binance.com/sapi/v1/broker/info?timestamp=${timestamp}&signature=${signature}&recvWindow=${recvWindow}`,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'X-MBX-APIKEY': apiKey
    }
  };

Comment: You need to add recvWindow to queryString before creating signature with queryString. All query parameters must be in in query signature.

Comment: Please can you edit my code : 
```
 //performe params
   const offset = 15000;
   const timestamp = moment().unix() * 1000 - offset;  // works flawlessly in my case
   const query_string = `timestamp=${timestamp}`;
   const recvWindow = 60000
   const signature = crypto.createHmac('sha256', secretKey).update(query_string).digest('hex')

  var url = `https://api.binance.com/sapi/v1/broker/subAccount?recvWindow=${recvWindow}&timestamp=${timestamp}&signature=${signature}&tag=${_tag}`;


```

Comment: Please don't just spam your code. I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot .

have you any documentation that you can share with me ?

Comment: https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#change-log
I can recommend reading the source code of node-binance-api:
https://github.com/jaggedsoft/node-binance-api
you can also implement it to save a lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

Just sync system time with network, is work for me.

Answer (score 0):

When I had this error, there were problems with the network connection. The requests did not reach Binance in time.

Answer (score 0):

reason is:
you have use "Thread.sleep" before you send query:

```
DepositQueryParam param = new DepositQueryParam();
Thread.sleep(1000);
this.walletAPIService.depositQuery(param);
```